# Pros and Cons of CouchDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc, couchdb

I'm looking at using CouchDB as a backend of an ASP.NET web API/web app which uses JSON heavily.

I'm interested in the pros and cons in terms of:

- replication
- platform dependency (currently all our servers are Windows 2003)
- ease of use (are there .NET libraries around?)

The application is not very transaction-intensive, probably about 100-200 CRUDs an hour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a little [comparism](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis) of CouchDB with other NoSQL databases. Here you'll find a [practical experience report](http://blog.bstovall.com/2012/02/09/couchdb-vs-mongodb-a-practical-experience/) comparing MongoDB and CouchDB. And you might also have a look into [this article](http://lucdebrouwer.nl/a-week-with-couchdb/) from a web developer perspective. (Maybe they are all a little outdated.)

You might be interested in [couchbrowse](http://code.google.com/p/couchbrowse/) ([SharpCouch](http://code.google.com/p/couchbrowse/source/browse/trunk/SharpCouch/SharpCouch.cs)) and [Ottoman](https://github.com/sinesignal/ottoman), too.

Answer (score 1):

Replication :Its really easy to configure the replication and mark for replication in couchDB.

Platform dependency : I tried setup-couchdb-1.2.0_otp_R15B.exe  on Windows 2003 x86 SP2 and succeeded.

Library : You can try LoveSeat/DreamSeat .Net client